# EF6 + Linq + RDLC report

Tags: linq, entity-framework-6, rdlc

```
 public IEnumerable GetDataForInvoicePDF(String _ProjectNumber, String _InvoiceNumber)
        {
            var result0 = (from blah in blah blah);

            var result1 =(from blah in blah blah);

            var resultx = (
                            from res0 in result0
                            join res1 in result1
                            on res0.EWONo equals res1.ItNo
                            into temp
                            from res1 in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
                            select new
                            {
                                EWONo = res0.EWONo ,
                                Stat = res0.Stat,
                                EWOVal = res0.Cost,
                                PctComp = (res0.TInv/ res0.Cost) * 100,
                                PBill =
                                    String.IsNullOrEmpty(res1.ItmInvAmnt.ToString()) ? res0.TInv : (res0.TInv - res1.ItmInvAmnt),
                                NewCharges =
                                    String.IsNullOrEmpty(res1.ItmInvAmnt.ToString()) ? 0 : res1.ItmInvAmnt,
                                AmntRem = res0.Cost - res0.TInv
                            }
                          );
            return resultx;
        }
```

I want to use the return data from the above function as the data source to a **TABLE** in **RDLC report**. I have gone through a lot of examples for entity framework data source for rdlc reports and using Linq with data sets, but I am stuck, none of those solutions are really useful to me.

Any tips would be appreciated, Thanks in advance !

Comment: Here is explained how to achieve what you're trying to do https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251784.aspx, you can't use an anonymous type

Comment: Thanks Raphael, I wasn't able to test this solution out, I was in a hurry, I used a stored procedure and data set as an alternative. I will try out your suggestion soon